# Movement of a ball rolling on a circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

I am trying to model the equation ruling the simple movement of a ball inside a circle structure (think of a 2D pendulum with no gravity looping on and on).

I assume the following equation of the movement:

$\theta(t) = c + b t + a t^2$ where $\theta(t)$ is the angle at time $t$. ($a,b,c$ are constant)

After some calculus, I found the equation of the movement for:

$\theta(t) = \theta(0) + \dot{\theta}(0) \times t + \frac{\ddot{\theta(0)}}{2} \times t^2$

My question is: How to estimate the constants $a,b,c$ when you know only the lap times at the origin?

By lap times, I mean, $t_1,...,t_n$ such that $\theta(t_1) = ... = \theta(t_n) = 0 [2 \pi]$ [when the pendulum passes in front of the origin).

I'm thinking of resolving a system where:

$c + b t_1 + a t_1^2 = 2 \pi\\
c + b t_2 + a t_2^2 = 4 \pi\\
c + b t_3 + a t_3^2 = 6 \pi$

and $t1, t2, t3$ are a sequence of consecutive lap times ($t_1 < t_2 < t_3$) for the first, second and third turns.

Do you know anything who could work?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the acceleration really constant?

Comment: And the physics concept here is what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a least squares fitting method. Say you have $n$ laps with times $t=(t_1,t_2,\ldots t_n)$ and displacements $\theta = (2\pi, 4\pi, \ldots 2\pi n)$.

Construct a $n \times 3$ [Vandermonde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) matrix

$$ V = \begin{vmatrix} 1 & t_1 & t_1^2 \\ 1 & t_2 & t_2^2 \\ \vdots & & \vdots \\ 1 & t_n & t_n^2 \end{vmatrix} $$

and a constants vector $k = (c,b,a)$ to be used as

$$ V k = \theta $$
$$ \begin{vmatrix} 1 & t_1 & t_1^2 \\ 1 & t_2 & t_2^2 \\ \vdots & & \vdots \\ 1 & t_n & t_n^2 \end{vmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c \\ b \\ a \end{pmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} 2\pi \\ 4\pi \\ \vdots \\ 2\pi n \end{vmatrix}$$

To fit for the coefficients do the following matrix algebra (it can be done in Excel)

$$  (V^\intercal V) k = V^\intercal \theta  $$ $$ k = (V^\intercal V)^{-1} V^\intercal \theta  $$

The matrix in the parenthesis is only a 3×3 so it is easy to invert. I typically use the `MINVERSE(a)`, `TRANSPOSE(a)` and `MMULT(a,b)` functions in `Excel`. Remember to use [array formula entering](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you for your very complete answer! Much appreciated!

Comment: @Tom Whittle: If you like this answer, then upvote it & if it is the answer you wanted or it helped you, then accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to solve for the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & t_1 & t_1^2\\
1 & t_2 & t_2^2\\
1 & t_3 & t_3^2\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
c\\
b\\
a\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
2\pi\\
4\pi\\
6\pi\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

and use the solutions to estimate $a,b,c.$.

Comment: You forgot to show the vector of $(a,b,c)$ in the equations above.

Comment: Yes you forgot the vector $(a,b,c)$ but I think everybody interested in this problem will get the main idea. Thank you!

Comment: Check your answer for the correct order of the coefficients.

Comment: @ja72 Thanks! Actually I had noticed it but the net connection suddenly became very slow. Corrected it now.